# How to set file permissions on a tree in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to figure out how to use Ansible to set permissions on a directory tree so that the default will be 644 as default (755 for directories, of course), except for a directory that needs 664/775 permissions.

The naive implementation would be this:

```
file:
    path: "mypath"
    mode: "u+rwX,go+rX,go-w"
    recurse: True

file:
    path: "mypath/exception"
    mode: "g+w"
    recurse: True
```

However, this is obviously not idempotent. With every run, mypath/exception will have the group-write permissions removed, and then immediately re-added.

The alternative is to enumerate each individual subdirectory in mypath/*, which I hope to avoid.

Is there another way to accomplish this in an idempotent way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `find` module to generate a list of paths, and then operate on those paths instead of using `recurse`.  For example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

    - find:
        paths:
          - mypath
        recurse: true
        file_type: any
      register: results

    - file:
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        mode: "u+rwX,go+rX,go-w"
      when: >-
        "mypath/exception" not in item.path
      loop: "{{ results.files }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.path }}"

    - file:
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        mode: "g+w"
      when: >-
        "mypath/exception" in item.path
      loop: "{{ results.files }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.path }}"
```

Running the above playbook against a sample directory tree yields something like:

```
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [find] ***********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [file] ***********************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=mypath/exception) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir2)
ok: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir3)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=mypath/exception/file3) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=mypath/exception/file2) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=mypath/exception/file1) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir2/dirc)
ok: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir2/dira)
ok: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir2/dirb)
ok: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir2/dirc/somefile)
ok: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir2/dira/somefile)
ok: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir2/dirb/somefile)
ok: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir3/dirc)
ok: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir3/dira)
ok: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir3/dirb)
ok: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir3/dirc/somefile)
ok: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir3/dira/somefile)
ok: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir3/dirb/somefile)

TASK [file] ***********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=mypath/exception)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir2) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir3) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=mypath/exception/file3)
ok: [localhost] => (item=mypath/exception/file2)
ok: [localhost] => (item=mypath/exception/file1)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir2/dirc) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir2/dira) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir2/dirb) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir2/dirc/somefile) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir2/dira/somefile) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir2/dirb/somefile) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir3/dirc) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir3/dira) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir3/dirb) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir3/dirc/somefile) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir3/dira/somefile) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=mypath/dir3/dirb/somefile) 

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

This playbook **will** be properly idempotent.

Comment: Thank you! Perfect. Well, close to it, but that's not your fault. Using the find module is far too slow and uses too much memory in my case; my directory tree has more than 100,000 files. If it wasn't for that, your approach would be the perfect solution! Thanks again!

Comment: And an extra thank you for the loop_control ... label construct. Another very useful little trick!